# how can we train two tensorflow model which one of them is a pre trained (frozen) network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have some difficulties in training two model which the outputs of the first model are the inputs of second model(the second model trained separately).

I have attached the schematic of the training process and models.
The first part for training the simulator model is okay. for training the generator, I have connect two models correctly but the results are far away from the expectation. my question is: should I define a custom training loop ? and how I can define the correct training loop?

below is the overall architecture of two connected models

```
input1 = keras.Input(shape=(100,), name='noise')
input2 = keras.Input(shape=(14,), name='contrast_vector')
[image_output, period_output] = generator([input1, input2])
Spectrum_output = simulator([image_output, period_output])
Final_model = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[image_output, 
period_output, Spectrum_output], name='Final_Model')

def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
return  tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, 1.0))


loss1 = ssim_loss
losses = [loss1, 'mse', 'mse']

Final_model.compile(
              loss= losses,
              loss_weights=[0.05, 0.01, 1.0],
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, beta_1=0.5))


 history = Final_model.fit([noise_train, CT_vector_train], [y_train, period_train, 
 full_spec_train], batch_size=256, epochs=1000, validation_split=0.2)
```

architecture of models:

[image: architecture of models]

Final_model plot in tensorflow:

[image: Final_model plot in tensorflow]

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is only passing the al ready existing input and output layers

```
Model(inputs=generator.inputs,
            outputs=simulator(generator.outputs))
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, in both cases it will produce loss=nan [loss: nan - Generator_loss: nan - Generator_1_loss: nan - model_loss: nan]

Comment: Oh I don't think that the model was the problem if you have nan is that you data don't match

Comment: I have checked the dataset many times. I don't think it is the data that making trouble. my assumption is that for the structure of this network the 'model.fit' is not suitable and I should define a custom training loop. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe is not the data but your loss function try adding `, axis=-1` to the reduce mean, if this not help try to using only one loss function to test if is the shape that cause this problem

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. actually I find the problem, because one of my outputs was binary(representing a binary image) it makes the gradient two steep and so the model couldn't train well. I changed the images to be in range(0,1) and the model works fine.